# Redirect Apache to Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have a server running Rails and Tomcat applications with Apache. I currently have a rails app setup to port 80 and a tomcat application on port 8080. I'm attempting to have Apache forward all requests on /uploader to tomcat. The tomcat application works OK when visiting it's own url, but when using the redirect it takes ~60 seconds per request. Here is my httpd file. Any help is really appreciated! Thanks!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName http://example.com/
  DocumentRoot /Users/lab/WebApplications/app/public   
  PassengerSpawnMethod conservative

    # Speeds up spawn time tremendously -- if your app is compatible. 
    # RMagick seems to be incompatible with smart spawning
    RailsSpawnMethod smart

    # Keep the application instances alive longer. Default is 300 (seconds)
    PassengerPoolIdleTime 1000

    # Keep the spawners alive, which speeds up spawning a new Application
    # listener after a period of inactivity at the expense of memory.
    RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 0

    # Just in case you're leaking memory, restart a listener 
    # after processing 5000 requests
    PassengerMaxRequests 5000
    # PassengerMaxPoolSize 4
    # PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 4



 <Directory /Users/lab/WebApplications/app/public>
     AllowOverride all              
Allow from all   
    Options -MultiViews            
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

    # Redirect to tomcat
ProxyPass         /uploader  http://localhost:8080/FileSplit
ProxyPassReverse  /uploader  http://localhost:8080/FileSplit
```

Comment: You might capture some traffic with `tcpdump` to see which side is sitting on the request for 60 seconds.

Comment: It's tenuous, but does changing the `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` make any difference?

Comment: you want `ProxyRequests Off` as that is for enabling forwarding proxying rather than ([what you need](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests)) reverse proxy with `ProxyPass`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but apache is probably waiting for your app to timeout before you get to the ProxyPass.  Try moving this to the top of the file, and see if that makes a difference.